# Set value of hidden field with corresponding data of item selected from AutoCompleteTextView

Tags: android, json, android-edittext, autocompletetextview

I've an `AutoCompleteTextView` that suggests name of place stored in MySQL database by calling an api, when text changes, using `onTextChanged`. Response is JSON array with many items like place_name, id, location_key,query_type, request_type, etc.(each with their own different purpose). I've 3 hidden EditText field. On `setOnItemClickListener`, when user selects a place name, I want these 3 hidden fields to have their value automatically set with location_key, query_type and request_type, as I need to send along these 3 values with place name to get required result from api.

Comment: And what's the problem? What did you try and what went wrong?

Comment: Post some code you have tried, so that we can improve on it.

Comment: Why do you store that info in hidden fields instead of just class member variables of your Actvity/Fragment?

Answer (score 0):

Once you click on the place_name field, the hidden EditTexts should get the values you need to send to the database. This can be easily obtained by doing the following:

```
textMessage.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        if (textMessage == "//Name of place") {
            editText1.setText "//whatever you need";
            editText2.setText "//whatever you need";
            editText3.setText "//whatever you need";
        }
    }
});
```

Alternatively, I would use a spinner for the place name and would code it with something similar to this:

@Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {

```
    int range = spnDonate.getSelectedItemPosition();

    Donator_Name = tboxName.getText().toString();
    switch(range) {
        case 0:
            editText1.setText = "//whatever you need";
            editText2.setText = "//whatever you need";
            editText3.setText = "//whatever you need";
            break;
        case 1:
            editText1.setText = "//whatever you need";
            editText2.setText = "//whatever you need";
            editText3.setText = "//whatever you need";
            break;
        case 2:
            editText1.setText = "//whatever you need";
            editText2.setText = "//whatever you need";
            editText3.setText = "//whatever you need";
            break;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Has this answer helped you?

Comment: Nope, I ended up using custom AutoCompleteTextView and set value accordingly

Comment: @carefree can you show how you did it  ? answer the question by yourself plz :)

Answer (score -1):

Set the visibility of these fields to gone .

```
 txtview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

and when you want to make them visible use

```
 txtPromo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Comment: I'm not asking how to make EditText field hidden, I'm asking how to populate these hidden fields with other data, corresponding to selected item, when user selects an item from autocomplete view.

Comment: This is not what the question is about. The EditTexts were already hidden.